# What do the "|" and ">>" means in Apache Beam?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam

I'm trying to understand Apache Beam. I was following the [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) and in one example, they say talk about `The following code example joins the two PCollections with CoGroupByKey, followed by a ParDo to consume the result. Then, the code uses tags to look up and format data from each collection.`.

I was quite surprised, because I didn't saw at any point a `ParDo` operation, so I started to wondering if the `|` was actually the `ParDo`. The code looks like this:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

emails_list = [
    ('amy', 'amy@example.com'),
    ('carl', 'carl@example.com'),
    ('julia', 'julia@example.com'),
    ('carl', 'carl@email.com'),
]
phones_list = [
    ('amy', '111-222-3333'),
    ('james', '222-333-4444'),
    ('amy', '333-444-5555'),
    ('carl', '444-555-6666'),
]

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    emails = p | 'CreateEmails' >> beam.Create(emails_list)
    phones = p | 'CreatePhones' >> beam.Create(phones_list)
    results = ({'emails': emails, 'phones': phones} | beam.CoGroupByKey())
    
    def join_info(name_info):
        (name, info) = name_info
        return '%s; %s; %s' %\
      (name, sorted(info['emails']), sorted(info['phones']))

    contact_lines = results | beam.Map(join_info)
```

I do notice that `emails` and `phones` are read at the start of the pipeline, so I guess that both of them are different `PCollections`, right? But where is the `ParDo` executed? What do the "|" and ">>" actually means? And how I can see the actual output of this? Does it matter if the `join_info` function, the `emails_list` and `phones_list` are defined outside the DAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `|` represents a separation between steps, this is (using `p` as `Pbegin`): `p  | ReadFromText(..) | ParDo(..) | GroupByKey()`.

You can also reference other `PCollections` before `|`:

```
read = p  | ReadFromText(..)
kvs = read | ParDo(..)
gbk = kvs | GroupByKey()
```

That's equivalent to the previous pipeline: `p  | ReadFromText(..) | ParDo(..) | GroupByKey()`

The `>>` are used between `|` and the `PTransform` to name the steps:  `p  | ReadFromText(..) |  "to key value" >> ParDo(..) | GroupByKey()`

Comment: To add to this, there are some tutorials available to learn Beam, you can check the Katas (available for Java and Python) and/or some new tutorials in Google Cloud under `Dataflow > Notebooks` by creating a new instance

Comment: Thanks @Iñigo. So, if I understood well, the `ParDo` operation is represented by the `>>` symbol, while the `|` represents different transformations to the `PCollections` that are performed in series, right? In the example you posted, is it necessary to use `ParDo`? Does `ParDo` open a new branch in the pipeline?

Comment: No no, the `>>` is simply an optional thing to name the step. The pardos are a `PTransform` by itself. Just to clarify: `p | "optional name" >> Ptransform`.  The `|` is a separator.

Comment: Ohh, so in the posted example, `beam.Create(emails_list)`, `beam.Create(phones_list)` and `beam.CoGroupByKey())` are the `ParDo`s or just the `beam.CoGroupByKey())`? And everytime a  new `PCollection` is created it has an implicit `ParDo`?

Comment: In that example, `Create` and `CoGroupByKey` (and `ParDo` FWIW) are `PTransforms`. `Create` generates the elements. `CoGroupByKey` is a way to aggregate N `PCollection`. `ParDo` is a general operation that is done element to element (for example, square a number, add one or whatever function). I would strongly suggest to go through either Katas or the Dataflow Notebooks to get the concepts right. I haven't gone through Katas (but they are released officially by Beam), but I know first hand that the Dataflow Notebooks have some theory and basic concepts in them.

Comment: You may also want to go through [Beam python transform catalog](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/overview/) and maybe start with simpler transforms (I'd say `CoGroupByKey` is one of thr hardest)

Comment: Thank you for your time and answers @Iñigo. I will check the resources you point me :). One last thing, what does FWIW stands for?

Comment: for what is worth :D .