# Understanding "|" and ">>" from the Beam Python example

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have some working knowledge about Python but pretty new to Apache Beam. I have encountered an example from Apache Beam about a simple word count program. The snippet that I'm confused looks like this:

```
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    # Read the text file[pattern] into a PCollection.
    lines = p | ReadFromText(known_args.input)

    # Count the occurrences of each word.
    counts = (
        lines
        | 'Split' >> (
            beam.FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\']+', x)).
            with_output_types(unicode))
        | 'PairWithOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))

    # Format the counts into a PCollection of strings.
    def format_result(word_count):
      (word, count) = word_count
      return '%s: %s' % (word, count)

    output = counts | 'Format' >> beam.Map(format_result)

    # Write the output using a "Write" transform that has side effects.
    # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
    output | WriteToText(known_args.output)
```

The full version of the code is here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_minimal.py

I'm very confused by the "|" and ">>" operators used here. What do they mean here? Are they natively supported in Python?

Comment: `Pipeline` objects have overwritten operators which do objects specific stuff. They are described in the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) (which has substantial room for improvement IMHO).

Comment: There is this same question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921747/what-do-the-and-means-in-apache-beam/64944798#64944798)

Comment: Thanks for linking the resources. I didn't think of operator overloading and thought this was something in Python idioms that I didn't know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this code is written in `Beam`, the symbols you are talking about are native to `Beam Pipeline`.
`|` is the pipeline symbol which indicates the pipeline being addressed to for the given operation: Like in your example, `p` is the source pipeline for `lines = p | ReadFromText(known_args.input)` and `lines` is the source pipeline for

```
counts = (
        lines
        | 'Split' >> (
            beam.FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\']+', x)).
            with_output_types(unicode))
        | 'PairWithOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
```

`>>` gives a name to a certain operation for ease of reading on the UI.

In your example, `'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))`, `GroupAndSum` is the name of the combine operation and so on.

Read the documentation given by @Klaus D. in the comments for more clarity.